# separate 2 digit numbers in fibonacci series

Tags: java

I'm trying to separate fibonacci sequence that are 2 digits long but the first digit is giving out zero's

```
    int[] fib = new int[input];
    int[] fib2 = new int[input];

    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    fib2[0] = 0;
    fib2[1] = 1;

for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {               
            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];  // first fibonnaci sequence to output
            fib2[i] = fib2[i - 1] + fib2[i - 2];  // second fibonnaci sequence to output
            fib[i] = separate(fib[i]);  //get the second digit of the fibonacci sequence
            fib2[i] = separate2(fib2[i]);//get the first digit of the fibonacci sequence but it output zero's
}

 public static int separate(int x) {
    //int result = x;
    x = x % 10;
    return x;
}

public static int separate2(int y) {
    //int result = x;
    y = y / 10;
    return y;
}
```

normal fibonacci sequence is
1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89
output should be 1,1,2,3,5,8,1,3,2,1,3,4,5,5,8,9

Comment: Can you post the values of `fib` both before and after the `for` loop?

Comment: Try printing what `x` and `y` are being passed to your methods, or use a debugger

Comment: What do you mean by "_separate fibonacci sequence that are 2 digits long_". Can you provide the output you expect. Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: normal fibonacci sequence is 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89 output should be 1,1,2,3,5,8,1,3,2,1,3,4,5,5,8,9

Comment: But you only have `0` in your `fib2` array... you don't declared the first two values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filling your arrays with the normal sequence before attempting to get single digits

```
for (int i = 2; i < input; i++)
{
    fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    fib2[i] = fib2[i - 1] + fib2[i - 2];
}

for (int i = 2; i < input; i++)
{
    fib[i] = separate(fib[i]);
    fib2[i] = separate2(fib2[i]);
}
```

Or with a bit of manipulation, only one sequence needs to be calculated to start

```
for (int i = 2; i < input; i++)
    fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];

for (int i = 2; i < input; i++)
{
    fib2[i] = separate2(fib[i]);
    fib[i] = separate(fib[i]);
}
```

Comment: You could only calculate the `fib` and in the second list swap the method order to use the same array in parameter. It would be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

First, you generate the list using an array not correct initialized. **(corrected in an edit.)**.

```
fib2[0] = 0; //first digit is 1 ... not 0 by the way
fib2[1] = 1;
```

The second problem is that you change the value of `fib[i]` but it is needed to calculate the next value, so you need to generate the full list first OR use distinct list.

But of course, why generate twice the list, one is enough, you can use different values to store the results (instead of erasing the previous values, needed the generate the next value°.

Use three arrays :

```
int[] fib = new int[input];
int[] fibDigit1 = new int[input];
int[] fibDigit2 = new int[input];

for (int i = 2; i < input; i++) {               
    fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];  // first fibonnaci sequence to output

    fibDigit1 = separate(fib[i]);
    fibDigit2 = separate2(fib2[i]);
}
```

Comment: no that value is only the first 2 in the fibonacci sequence, the loop is the one giving the value 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,

Comment: Won't setting `fib[i]` to a non-fib number mess with future values?  You may need a `realFib` array or something

Comment: Yes but to generate the list, you need the first two values... in `fib1` you try to generate the list with `0`and `0`

Comment: @phflack yep, noticed that just now... `fib` should not be touch to be able to generate the complete list.

Comment: Looks like the initial fib numbers might've been edited in

Comment: Three array, one for the values, the others for the results is simpler (bases on what is needed for each values). If the list is not needed after, @phflack answer is better (one less array to store)